# node js server doesn't get started

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a server.js file that will be used to start a node server and do some tasks. But when i run the file, the server doesn't getting started. Even i have catch the error it doesn't give me any errors. Any help would be appriciated!

Thanks.

below is my server.js file code block,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');  

//--ssl files for the socket.io
var options = {

key: fs.readFileSync('pre3private.key'),

cert: fs.readFileSync('pre3cert.cert')

};
//--/ssl files for the socket.io 

var https = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var net = require('net'); 

var check_port = 8081; 

var server = net.createServer();

server.once('error', function(err) {
 console.log(err);
 if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
  // port is currently in use
  check_port += 1;
  if(check_port === 8050) { check_port = 8000; }
  server.listen(check_port);
 }
});

server.once('listening', function() {
 // close the server if listening doesn't fail
 server.close();

 var port = process.env.PORT || check_port;

 https.listen(port, function(){
  debug('Server started! at port ' + port);
 });                 

});
```

Comment: does **anything** get output to the console at all?

Comment: How are you attempting to run it?

Comment: @JaromandaX No nothing at all.that's the issue. thanks

Comment: @Goliadkin i'm running it just typing " node server.js" in the terminal.

Comment: Why are you creating two separate server objects?  Why are you only starting one if the other gets a listening message.  This is very weird logic.  What is the point of that unusual logic?  What are you trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `server.listen(check_port);` at the end of your code, to **try** the first port

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you suggested I have put server.listen(check_port) part outside of the server.once('listening'... and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move the 'https.listen(' part outside of "server.once('listening'...", but I think that there are other issues in that code.

I recommend to start with a clean example from https://nodejs.org/api/net.html (or express) run it without changes to see that it works and then add your changes incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have put server.listen(check_port) part outside of the server.once('listening'... and it worked!